# Can I use the server ip as its fully qualified hostname?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, hostname

I am setting up a dedicated mysql box, and I am not assigning any domain name to it, as it will be a backend server.

Can I set its ip address as its fully qualified hostname?

I am installing virtualmin and it requires a fully qualified hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP addresses are not any kind of hostname, fully-qualified or otherwise. But the software might accept the address regardless. Or you could take all of 15 seconds and add an entry to `/etc/hosts`...

Answer (score 3):

An FQDN is the full domain name localized into the DNS hierarchy, for instance `mysql-backend.example.lan.`

An IP address is not a FQDN.

If your software requires you a FQDN please evaluate to add a record to your DNS server cache or to `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.9.200 mysql-backend.example.lan mysql-backend
```